# Running KakaoTalk on Playonlinux

Tags: lubuntu, playonlinux

I see the following Error:

[image: PlayonLinux Error]

saying

```
This system is not supported.
Please contract Customer Service.
Current version: 2.6.1.1618
```

My OS is Lubuntu Artful.
And I tried to run `KakaoTalk` with `Playonlinux`.
**How can I fix this error?**

Comment: I got it installed, but during PC registration, the app freezes

Answer (score 0):

I had various issues with getting KakaoTalk to run on my Ubuntu 16.04, and the **[instructions here](http://blog.igk.me/2014/04/ubuntu-1404-pc-wine.html)** finally did the trick and got it working. It's in Korean but the screenshots make it fairly intuitive. Firstly go with the option to "Install a non-listed program". Then choose to "Install some libraries". The installation of two additional libraries (POL_Install_gdiplus & POL_Install_riched20) seems to be what's needed to get KakaoTalk to work fully.